# How can I disable "Middle-Click to Close" in Window Overview?

Tags: release-freya, window-management, multitasking-view

In Elementary OS Freya (0.3.2), if an item is middle-clicked on in Window Overview (super + w), such as Google Chrome or Terminal, that process is closed/killed. Is there anyway to disable this feature?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have a trackpad with a large middle click zone.  Accidentally closing windows is the **worst**.

So, I disabled middle click in terminal:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 99 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

This takes effect immediately.  Then if I start using a mouse, where again I want middle click to work, I run the reverse command:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

You can put `pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` into the file `~/.Xmodmap` to setup a persistent default that will take effect when you login.

I'd LOVE to find a better fix.